# When sending GET to IIS 10 web server - ASP pages get 301 error, all other content is retrieved with a 200

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, webforms

I'm not very familiar with IIS but I'm baffled. I inherited an old website written in ASP. It was working fine on a server with IP address "74.xxx..". , which is where the domain  "**mydomain.org**" is pointing.

A design company is building a new website at IP address "165.xxx...". They are starting with the home page, with links to some pages at the old website until they finish the site.

So I created a subdomain "**oldsite.mydomain.org**" for their links and copied the old website subdirectory in IIS, to a new subdirectory,  created a new website mirroring the old website. So far, so good.

While the subdomain has the same IP address as **mydomain.org** the new subdomain works fine and behaves exactly as the old site does. After I point **mydomain.org** to the design company's server at IP of 165..xxx, IIS refuses to serve the ASP pages and returns a 301 error.

At first I thought it was a security issue and got a new SSL cert for just the subdomain.  Using whynopadlock.com, security checks out fine.

In fact, I can ask for a piece of content - .txt file, .htm file, .mp3 etc. from **oldsite.mydomain.org** and it happily returns the content. But when I ask for **oldsite.mydomain.org/index.aspx** or other asp page it returns a 301.

I've run a trace and the error seems to be originating in the ISAPI module,but there's no other information.

Obviously  there's something in the configuration that's giving the 301 error but I"ve looked at everything I can think of and can't find it. Wondering if the name **mydomain.org** is hard coded in the ASP pages but don't see it anywhere I've looked. Also there is no HTTP redirect set on the server.

Why is it giving a 301 error only on ASP pages and not on the other content?

TIA,

Jimaa

Comment: An HTTP Status Code of [`301 MOVED PERMANENTLY`](https://httpstatuses.com/301) is not an error code it’s a redirection code. Somewhere in the ASP.Net code there is a `Response.Redirect` or `Response.StatusCode = 301` line.

Comment: Also question was tagged [tag:asp-classic] but it’s clear from the sample url you provide you’re serving [tag:asp.net] webform pages (.aspx).

Comment: Have you added a custom error page in iis? In order to get detailed message about the 301, you can try to use the [failed requests tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Yes indeed, it's asp.net - I was confused because the Application Pool was set to "classic" rather than integrated.

Comment: Using request tracking as samwu suggested, I've found the module that is giving the 301 message but I don't know where to go from here. As a reminder, when the TLD is at the same address as the subdomain the ASP pages are served, it's only when the TLD domain is moved that I get the redirect. 

ModuleName IsapiModule
Notification EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
HttpStatus 301
HttpReason Moved Permanently

Comment: can you show me the module about the 301 message in the log file?

Comment: Found the problem - near the top of the .ASAX file is this code:*                               
**if (lcase(currentHost) <> "www.example.org" OR https = false) and instr(currentHost,"hudson") = 0  Then
Dim _Path as string = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("PATH_INFO")
if _Path = "/index.aspx" Then
_Path = "/"
End if
HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently"
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", "https://www.example.org"  & _Path)
End if**         BTW, Hudson Design built the site. Why would they want put this code in?